# How can I convert a string containing an equation into a double-precision value?

Tags: string, matlab, double

I have the following string:

```
A = 'A = cos(2*pi*f1*t) + 4*sin(2*pi*f2*t)';
```

And have defined the variables `f1` and `f2` (two frequency values) and `t` (a vector of time points). How I can convert the equation in `A` to a double-precision value?

I tried:

```
B = str2num(A);  % Result is an empty matrix
```

and:

```
B = str2double(A);  % Result is a NaN value
```

and:

```
B = double(A);
```

But no luck. How can I do this?

Comment: what result do you expect  with having `f1` and `t` in it?

Comment: Are you sure you have a string in `A`? It seems to me that A is either a vector or symbolic expression.

Comment: I expect to have a vector of type double like : 1x300 for exemple. And it represent a signal
And Yes I'm sure it's a string because, it's générated in a uicontrol with type 'String' and 'Style' = 'Edit'

Comment: Are `f1`, `f2`, and `t` defined as variables?

Comment: `f1` and `f2` are two frenquencies defined and `t` is a time vector also defined

Comment: You shouldn't be having a string like that in the first place.

Comment: Can you try eval('A = cos(2*pi*f1*t) + 4*sin(2*pi*f2*t)')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a string like so:

```
str = 'A = cos(2*pi*f1*t) + 4*sin(2*pi*f2*t)';
```

And your variables `f1`, `f2`, and `t` have been defined, you would need to use [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) to evaluate the string (and you might want to add a `';'` to the end to suppress output to the screen):

```
eval([str ';']);
```

It should be noted that `eval` [isn't usually the best option](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html), even though sometimes it may be unavoidable. It can have unintended consequences. For example, if a user entered `clear all` into your uicontrol, it would erase your workspace. They might also inadvertently shadow a function by making a bad choice of variable name, like entering `sin = sin(2*pi*f*t)`. In other words, you should usually try to find alternatives that don't require `eval` to function.

Comment: Ok thank's a lot, I don't known this function and thank's for explanations ! :-)